# Flexible Width Tag Counts

Tags: feature-request, tags, voting, design

The following picture was taken from [Jon Skeet's tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=tags) on Stack Overflow.

[image: Tags Page]

As you can see, the `54k` count fits centered in its container, but for counts greater than 99k, the count is no longer centered.

I'm requesting that `div.answer-votes` tags be made flexible width to allow for votes totaling 100k or greater.

Comment: Yet another case where Jon Skeet is literally too good for SO to handle.

Comment: We ought to reset all his rep and badges to 0. Teach him to sabotage the site.

Comment: @AmericanLuke That would only delay the issue. Maybe a couple of hours, tops.

Comment: I hope `1M` would be used when he gets `1000k`. I was going to suggest using `0.1M` instead of `101k`, but that's inconsistent (since `999` isn't shown as `0.99k`)